# Wordpress Custom Post Type Template

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website. I need to add custom Post types. I have created a custom post type `products` which has a taxonomy `product_type` which is similar to `category` . There are various taxonomy value for `product_type` . Some of them are `flowers`, `extracts` etc .

Now I am trying to visit this link `http://farma.mechadigital.net/products/product_type/flowers/` and it doesnt work for me.

I have added some files.

```
archive-products => This should be the custom post template
taxonomy-product_type.php => This should be the taxonomy Template
taxonomy-product_type-flowers.php => This should be the template for the term value flowers
```

Here is the code that I have included in functions.php. I dont know where I am doing it wrong.

**functions.php**

```
   function farma_products() {
        $labels = array(
            // List of arguments
        );

        $args = array(
            // list of arguments
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
        );


        register_post_type( 'products', $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules(false);
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'farma_products_type' );

    function farma_products_type() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'product_type',
            'products',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Product Type' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products/product_type' ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Have you re-saved your permalinks by going to your admin settings and clicking "save"?

Comment: try removing the rewrite, reset your permalinks to default and access the page from the category -> View. This should give you an idea if it's working.